# Uncertainty in spatio-temporal forecasting

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, stochastic-processes, gaussian-process

We have a time series gridded panel dataset (spatio-temporal). The dataset is in 3D, where each (x,y,t) coordinate has a numeric value (such as the sea temperature at that location and at that specific point in time). So we can think of it as a matrix with a temporal component. The dataset is similar to this but with just one channel:

[image: Dataset]

I am trying to predict/forecast the nth time step values for the whole region (i.e., all x,y coordinates in the dataset) given the values for the n-1 time steps and the uncertainty.

Can you all suggest any model/architecture/approach for the same? I was initially thinking of the [Log-Gaussian Cox Process](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4616515) but it seems it's mostly applicable to point processes, while my dataset is gridded with each grid having a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

Markov random fields address "neighborhoods", in your case neighbors in time and space. In computer vision, four-neighbor (N-E-S-W) and eight-neighbor models are prevalent (N-NE-E-SE-S-SW-W-NW).

If necessary (start first with a simple model), you could model larger neighborhoods with "filters", using techniques similar to Zhu, Wu, and Mumford. "Filters, random fields and maximum entropy (FRAME): Towards a unified theory for texture modeling." International Journal of Computer Vision 27 (1998): 107-126. I define several hundred element "neighborhoods" with exchange traded funds (ETFs) in my paper Keane "Portfolio Variance Constraints." ICPRAM. 2019.

A nice framework for *n-th time step values* is West and Harrison. *Bayesian forecasting and dynamic models.* Springer Science & Business Media, 2006. The framework uses discrete timesteps as you do, time-of-day or time-of-year  cyclical components are addressed, as are matrix variate models.